# Invoking another phonegap app in iPhone using URL Scheme

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have 2 phonegap applications installed in my iPhone. I want to open one app from the other one.
I am able to load other app when I click the button on the current application.

```
<a  href="mycoolapp://"  id="btnopen">Open</a>
```

But I want to open the other app without a user action. One has to automatically invoke other one when some event like document.ready fires,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#btnopen").click();  

});
```

But the above code doesn't work. How can I invoke the other app using script & without a user action?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#btnopen').trigger('click');`

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I tried the above code also, but facing the same issue. The event is getting generated but its not opening the other app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could resolve the issue with below code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#btnopen").click();  

  $("#btnopen").bind("click",function() {

    window.location= "mycoolapp://" ;

  });

});
```